# Using AD FS 4.0 LDAP integration with IIS in Server 2016

Tags: windows, active-directory, iis, windows-server-2016, adfs

I am considering using AD FS 4.0 in an upcoming Server 2016 deployment, principally because of its support for authenticating users stored in an external LDAP directory.  However, I've read in some of the docs that this feature only supports forms-based authentication at this time, though some other documentation I've encountered does not mention such a limitation.

Does anyone here know if it is definitely the case that accounts stored in an external LDAP directory can only be used for Web-site based forms authentication in Server 2016 ?  If LDAP cannot be used to (for example) authenticate users for FTP login purposes with AD FS 4.0 then I'll probably skip this in this particular deployment, but if it is possible to authenticate against LDAP for IIS login purposes then this could be worth our time.

Thanks in advance to anyone who might be able to provide some clarification here.  If anyone would like more information before answering please let me know and I'll be happy to assist.

Answer (score 0):

ADFS supports LDAP authentication and authorisation in exactly the sane way it treats AD authentication and authorisation i.e. FBA and WIA.

What do you mean by "FTP login"?